# WebView has been removed from React Native

Tags: react-native

*i didnt do anything on project for 5 months maybe. I try to run now but it gives me this error:*

[image]

*I dont use WebView why i am getting this error ? and also i installed react-native-webview but error is still not going*

these are my dependencies which i use :

[image]

[image]

Comment: actually why you give - ? maybe other people have this error too. you shouldnt give -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could try to search all the project about `webView`(especially in node modules), find out where use this tag.
2. Check if that modules have update? if yes, upgrade it. Or go to that page and change like this:

```js
import { WebView } from  'react-native';

//change to below

import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';//because you have install the new react-native-webview
```

And it should work well...

--update for picture--
[image]

Comment: how can i search webview word in all project ?. and also i dont use import { WebView } from  'react-native' anywhere in project

Comment: If you don't, it should be the third modules used, one or more modules import it using like first line(old version), which IDE are you using? I use VSCode have search function
 to find all project..

Comment: At the left have a magnifier, click it and insert "WebView "

Comment: if it is possible can u share  picture please ?  i think i am doing wrong things :)

Comment: Add in answer there

Comment: But if it got error, it should give where the page using it, isn't it?

Comment: I got one of it, in your `react-native-html-parser` using `import React, { WebView,} from 'react-native'`  [Here](https://github.com/g6ling/react-native-html-parser)

Comment: oh man i changed it in two place including "react-native-html-parser" but still got error. this is soooo annoying

Comment: You have to find out all the place use like `import { WebView } from 'react-native'` this ....

Comment: Or you could use document search in node modules with text inside search... have to wait for some times..

Comment: You just look into each one, find out which import as an old style and update to new one. Others could ignore. By the way, there are so many(your file).....

Comment: thank you so much for help. i am trying  to solve now

Comment: are u here ? i did everything what i can, but it still same error really  there is no more import { WebView } from 'react-native' but it gives still same error :////

Comment: or maybe you could try to `$ ./gradlew clean` and run again? There is only one way to solved this question by replace wrong import...

Comment: i did it so many times but error still exists. i dont know what to do. anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use some third-party Modules from NPM which depends on webview.
You should check this and upgrade the needed Package.

Maybe do an full-text-search in your "node_modules" for it. Or provide more information what your app does and which components it use.

Comment: I added my dependencies @suther

Comment: You see in your package.json `react-native-webview`. There it is ?!!

Comment: Ok, so you installed it or it was still there???!!!, but what you have to do now is to search the places in your app, where you import the WebView and replace it to be imported from this new package: `import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';`